# When does a child start showing jealousy?

Tags: behavior, development

At what age is it normal for a child to begin showing signs of jealousy of other children?

I ask because my 13-month-old God daughter seemed like she was a little resentful of another child who was visiting at the same time.

Comment: Welcome to Parenting! Could you add some more detail about what you observed -- was it a specific moment or interaction (perhaps about a toy?) or just a general attitude?

Answer (score 1):

I have twin boys and it was certainly obviously well before one was a year old that he was jealous of any attention that his brother got. It took a while longer before he starting showing any brotherly feeling, and even then, it appeared to be more to get praise or a good reaction from the surrounding adults. By three, he was better about not being always trying to get more attention than his brother.

Comment: On my second child's 8 month doctor visit, I asked him about jealousy. I was surprised an 8 month old *second child* could be jealous of the attention I gave to the first. I'll never forget the look of disbelief on his face (he thought it should be perfectly obvious that babies that young can be jealous.) So, yes, I agree wholeheartedly with this answer. :-)

Answer (score 0):

That is the most normal thing in the world. You should watch yourself, see if you're giving her all the attention you could, because she needs it. If you think you're doing your part well and she is still jealous, don't worry anymore, because it happens.

Comment: I was sure to give them both attention, but the other child is a one off visit. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is older, but I wanted to say, my 2nd born was immediately possessive of me.  I was rather shocked by this.  Even in his first week of life, if my other child (toddler) wanted to sit on my lap, the newborn would not let me hold him *and* the other child.  He would arch his back, unlatch if he was mid-nursing, and scream.  He would not settle until he had me to himself, no matter how many times I tried (I kept thinking he would "get used to it").  He was otherwise a very laid back baby that seldom cried or fussed over anything.  He was also okay for me to give attention to his sibling *when* he was content and not wanting me, but if he was in my lap, any attention I would give to the other would send him into screeching and arching, sometimes even if I *talked* to the other child  It was very new to me, but apparently they can show some of this from birth even.

Answer (score 0):

My daughter started getting jealous at 5 months. I was really shocked to see that. Her brother can't even touch me. The animals can't even comes close to me, lol.